# GraphQL mutation without sub section

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I want to send graphql mutation request without sub section

```js
mutation _ {
    updateCurrentUser(fullName: "Syava", email: "fake@gmail.com")
}
```

and I am getting

```js
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Field \"updateCurrentUser\" of type \"User\" must have a sub selection.",
      ... 
    }
  ]
}
```

add { id } to request works fine but I don't want

Also Schema code

```
const userType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
    fullName: { type: GraphQLString },
    email: { type: GraphQLString },
  }),
});

type: userType,
  args: {
    fullName: { type: GraphQLString },
    email: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(emailType) },
    password: { type: GraphQLString },
  },
  resolve: async (root, { fullName, email, password }, { rootValue }) => {
    const user = await User.findById(rootValue.req.user.id);

    ...

    return user;
  },
```

Answer (score 16):

You define the type of the field to be UserType. Even though it's a mutation, it still follows the same rules and behavior as a query. Because UserType is an object type, it requires nested fields.

```
mutation _ {
  updateCurrentUser(fullName: "Syava", email: "fake@gmail.com") {
    fullName
    email
  }
}
// would respond with { fullName: 'Syava', email: 'fake@gmail.com' }
```

If you don't want the mutation to return a User, you can declare its type to GraphQLBoolean for example -- that's a scalar and doesn't have any nested fields.

```
{
  type: GraphQLBoolean,
  args: {
    fullName: { type: GraphQLString },
    email: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(emailType) },
    password: { type: GraphQLString },
  },
  resolve: async (root, { fullName, email, password }, { rootValue }) => {
    const user = await User.findById(rootValue.req.user.id);
    user.fullName = fullName;
    user.password = password; // or hashed to not store plain text passwords
    return user.save(); // assuming save returns boolean; depends on the library you use
  }
}
```

Note that the best practice for mutations in GraphQL APIs is to return a "result" object with multiple fields, such as the mutated object itself (e.g. `user`), `clientMutationId` (per Relay spec), and others as needed. This makes it flexible so you could add more data in the future.

```
updateCurrentUser(fullName: "Syava", email: "fake@gmail.com") {
  clientMutationId
  user {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you make this answer better understandable by adding graphql schema examples or graphql-js type definitions?

Comment: In case this mutation is called from several parts of the code, maybe sometimes the response should be of type: "userType" and some other times no response is needed.
Is there a way to get an optional "userType" response and sub selecting datas according to the client constraints??

Comment: With `type: userType`, the server says it returns a *possibly null* user (with `type: GraphQLNonNull(userType)`, the user would be guaranteed to be present). Regardless, the server needs to specify how to fetch the user. If it can be `null` for certain cases, the client should make sure before accessing its attributes.

> according to the client constraints
The client cannot constrain the return type. What you can do is ask for `updateCurrentUser(...) { id }` and simply ignore what's returned. But you can't ask for `updateCurrentUser(...)` with no attributes.